# Password/username using switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

Code works good, but when I enter wrong Username, it just terminates without any output. Any tips or advice for this code? I know I can use `if... else`, but I'm trying to do this with `switch`.

```
package frame.security;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FrameIntel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String Username;
        System.out.println("Enter Username:" );
        Username=sc.nextLine();
        String Password;
        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        Password=sc.nextLine();

        switch(Username) {
        case"Winford Coloma":
            if("TwelveEleven".equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("Senior Software Engineer");
                System.err.println("Limited Access to Sandbox!(4)");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Access Denied!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        case"Lynelle Marten":
            if("TwelveSixteen".equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("Test Administrator");
                System.err.println("Limited Access to Sandbox!(5)");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Access Denied");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        case"Luis Ansley":
            if("TwelveTwenty".equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("Software Engineer");
                System.err.println("Controlled Access to Sandbox!(Clog)");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Access Denied");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        case"Shantay Dority":
            if("TwelveTwentyFour".equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("Programmer");
                System.err.println("Implement only(Sandbox)!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Access Denied");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        case"Tangela Norsworthy":
            if("TwelveTwentySeven".equals(Password)){
                System.out.println("CEO");
                System.err.println("Full access to Sandbox!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Access Denied");
                System.exit(0);
            } 


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need `default` here.

Comment: [The `default` section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the `case` sections.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `default` statement, so your code will only work with the usernames written within your `case` statements

Answer (score 0):

You are using **switch** statement without **default** case.
The default case is used when no "case" hits match.

add these lines after your case`"Tangela Norsworthy"`:

```
default: {
    System.err.println("Username not recognised");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

`0` in "`System.exit();`" indicates, that application exited without problems. You should use other values as indication there was some problem. (i.e System.exit(1) --> 1 = invalid username, System.exit(2) --> 2 = invalid password)